# EntityLayer not linking to MapView

Tags: android, bing-maps

I am trying to display multiple `Pushpin` objects on an `EntityLayer` for Bing Maps. While the `Pushpins` are retrieving data correctly and the `EntityLayer` is storing the `Pushpins` properly, the `MapView` is not displaying the `EntityLayer`.

```
JSONObject json = retrieveJSON();
JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("Sites");

Coordinate closestGauge;

fooLayer = new EntityLayer("foos");


for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject site = array.getJSONObject(i);
    double lon = site.getDouble("Longitude");
    double lat = site.getDouble("Latitude");
    Pushpin foo = null;
    fooCoordinate = new Coordinate(lat, lon);
    PushpinOptions fooData = new PushpinOptions();
    fooData.Text = Double.toString(site.getDouble("Data"));
    fooData.Icon = Constants.PushpinIcons.RedFlag;
    foo = new Pushpin(fooCoordinate, fooData);
    _FWSGPSLayer.add(foo);
}

fooMap.getLayerManager().addLayer(fooLayer);
fooLayer.updateLayer();
```

Going by the Debug perspective, I noted that the `EntityLayer` never links to the `MapView` as its `_map` parameter/value is always set to `null`. I've tried various ways of displaying the layer, such as calling the `setBingMapsView` method from `EntityLayer` but nothing has worked so far.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I tried to match things up with the sample Bing Maps application, it hasn't been helping.

EDIT: I've done some debugging and this is what I've found out so far: When I comment out the for loop and simply add a single Pushpin, it works. This leads me to believe that Bing Maps has a limit for the number of Pushpins that can be added. However, my array only contains ~200 data points whereas I have been led to believe that the upper limit is in the thousands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, silly me. Scouring through my `JSONArray`, I noticed that, interspersed throughout my array, a couple of `Doubles` were actually returning `null`. Of course, since I was debugging on an Android device with a near-constant stream of `Location` updates, I could hardly spot the `NullPointerException` in my LogCat.

Lesson learned, always check for `nulls`.